# Prequisite for homology theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology, self-learning

I have almost finished  Hatcher topology  section $1.1$  but not $1.2$(Van Kampen's theorem)  and $1.3$( covereing space)

Now  my question  is that

**Can I directly jump into  $2$nd chapter homology theory**?

Will I face any difficulty in understanding   if i will not read Van Kampen and covering space topics.Actually i don't want to read   $1.2$(Van Kampen's theorem)  and $1.3$( covereing space).I want to skip these  two topics

I have seen many books of algebraics Toplogy where fundamental group chapter is not included.

Also,i want to know  the about the prequisite for homology theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homology chapter of Hatcher does not logically depend on 1.2 and 1.3. All chapters of Hatcher are pretty much independent of each other(not logically, but you can pretty much start from any chapter and go backwards whenever necessary). However, Van Kampen and covering spaces are important, skipping them would be unwise.

Hatcher is basically self-contained. I don't think one needs extra prerequisite to understand the homology chapter.